# pandas ImportError: cannot import name hashtable on Mac OS X

Tags: python, pandas

I recently noticed I had an old version of pandas installed on my machine (0.10).

I tried pip install -U first and got the error. I pip uninstalled, wiped any old directories, pip installed again and still the same error. I even tried building from the git, but whatever I seem to do, I get the same error:

```
In [8]: import pandas
cannot import name hashtable
cannot import name hashtable
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-d6ac987968b6> in <module>()
----> 1 import pandas

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
      5 
      6 try:
----> 7     from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
      8 except Exception:  # pragma: no cover
      9     import sys

/Users/kcampbell/pandas/tslib.pyx in init pandas.tslib (pandas/tslib.c:77195)()

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
      5 
      6 try:
----> 7     from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
      8 except Exception:  # pragma: no cover
      9     import sys

ImportError: cannot import name hashtable
```

My numpy, pytz, python-dateutil are all up to date

```
In [1]: import numpy

In [2]: numpy.__version__
Out[2]: '1.9.1'

In [3]: import pytz

In [4]: pytz.__version__
Out[4]: '2014.9'

In [5]: import dateutil

In [6]: dateutil.__version__
Out[6]: '1.5'
```

When installing from pip, it is spitting out a bunch of stuff during what I guess is the build process. For example, this gets repeated a lot:

```
In file included from pandas/index.c:235:
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:73:10: warning: static variable 'PyArray_API' is used in an inline function with external linkage [-Wstatic-in-inline]
  return PyArray_IsScalar(obj, Datetime);
         ^
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:49:35: note: expanded from
      macro 'PyArray_IsScalar'
        (PyObject_TypeCheck(obj, &Py##cls##ArrType_Type))
                                  ^
<scratch space>:84:1: note: expanded from here
PyDatetimeArrType_Type
^
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1381:50: note: expanded from
      macro 'PyDatetimeArrType_Type'
#define PyDatetimeArrType_Type (*(PyTypeObject *)PyArray_API[215])
                                                 ^
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/object.h:439:60: note: expanded from macro 'PyObject_TypeCheck'
    (Py_TYPE(ob) == (tp) || PyType_IsSubtype(Py_TYPE(ob), (tp)))
                                                           ^
pandas/src/numpy_helper.h:71:1: note: use 'static' to give inline function 'is_datetime64_object' internal linkage
PANDAS_INLINE int
^
static 
pandas/src/helper.h:6:27: note: expanded from macro 'PANDAS_INLINE'
    #define PANDAS_INLINE __inline__
                          ^
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:812:15: note: 'PyArray_API'
      declared here
static void **PyArray_API=NULL;
```

I've run python and ipython from different directories to test the "Can't run from source directory" idea. At this point I'm out of things to try. I do have Cython installed for when I tried to install from the git. 
I did previously have an anaconda install that I got rid of, so I'm fairly sure I don't have any stray installs lying around somewhere?

I'm at a loss at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is `/Users/kcampbell/pandas/` the directory where your own programs are, or the source to Pandas itself? If it's the former, you appear to be trying to run your own Cython programs, and it may just be that you need to force them to re-cythonize and re-compile to pick up the new Pandas. If the latter, you're probably getting a jumbled mix of installed and in-tree Pandas modules which is confusing everything, so just `cd` somewhere else. (And if you did the `pip` from that directory, undo it and redo it from somewhere else.)

Comment: /Users/kcampbell/ is where my own programs are. I was running pip from that directory. /Users/kcampbell/pandas does not currently exist! cython is elsewhere:
kcampbell-mpb:~ kcampbell$ which cython

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/cython

Comment: How would I re-cythonize and re-compile? This is new territory for me. Whatever directory I go to with my interpreter, it looks for that file in ./pandas/tslib.pyx.

Comment: OK, first, the "re-cythonize and re-compile" was only if you were writing your own Cython code. Since you have no idea how to do that, you don't have to worry about it. Which is good.

Comment: For the other part… it sounds like pandas somehow got built wrong. Can you uninstall it, and do a clean install from within a directory that has absolutely nothing in it (and isn't called `pandas`), just to be completely safe?

Comment: I did 'sudo pip uninstall pandas' and deleted the directory that was in '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/'. I then created '/temp' and ran 'sudo pip install pandas' from there. It seems to have worked! Thank you @abarnert!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, the problem was that your pandas installation was screwed up.

The most likely reason for this is that you were inside a directory named `pandas` when you did the `pip install pandas`, which caused some of the build steps to pick up relative paths to the local directory instead of paths to the temporary directory where the build happens. Of course that *shouldn't* happen, but with a build based on custom Python and Cython code as complicated as Pandas, it's not all that surprising. If you could reproduce the problem, I'd file a bug upstream, but I'm guessing that wouldn't be easy.

Anyway, whatever the reason, the solution is the same: uninstall it, then make sure you're in a directory that isn't named `pandas` and doesn't have anything named `pandas` in it, then reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I had so much trouble getting c-based modules to work/compile on my mac, until someone pointed me at MacPorts https://www.macports.org/ - in my opinion it's a well supported, up-to-date package delivery system that serves python really well - some of the more obscure packages aren't provided, but I've not come across a mainstream one yet that's not supported.

I just checked and cython is part of the supported packages.

```
port search cython

...various flavours of cython found for differing versions of python...
...including...

py34-cython @0.21.1 (python, devel)
A language for writing C extension modules for Python.
```

So not a direct answer, I know, but maybe something worth trying?

Comment: He already has Cython. And a working Python. And he wants Python 2.7, not 3.4. Also, I believe he already has Homebrew, which you don't want to mix with MacPorts. (MacPorts is better if you want a completely parallel set of software, independent of everything provided by Apple or any common third-party installations; Homebrew is better if you want software that integrates with the rest of your system.)